# swfobject doesn't load blip.tv swf properly in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, flash, swfobject

I'm using swfobject (2.2) to load blip.tv videos. Everything was working fine with their old player, but now that they have switched to the stratos player, it fails to load properly in IE.  It shows a grey video window, with the play button half showing on the left side, and the button won't work.

Here is my js code:

```
function loadBlip(videoFile,width,height,cssID) {
    var blipSWF = "http://blip.tv/scripts/flash/stratos.swf";
    var expressSWF = "/lib/js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf";
    var attributes = {
        name: cssID,
        id: cssID
    };
    var flashvars = {
        file: videoFile,
        allowsriptaccess: "true",
        expressinstall: expressSWF,
        allowfullscreem: "true",
        enablejs: "true",
        javascriptid: cssID,
        lightcolor: "0xFFFFFF",
        backcolor: "0x000000",
        autostart: "false",
        showinfo: "false"
    };
    var params = {
        wmode: "opaque",
        allowfullscreen: "true",
        allowScriptAccess: "always"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(blipSWF, cssID, width, height, "9.0.124", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
}
```

The file that I pass to the loadBlip function looks like: "http://blip.tv/rss/flash/3403588".

Again, this works fine in FF/Chrome/Safari, but fails in IE.

Here's a sample link: http://bit.ly/k6pdae

Thanks!

Comment: One thing that may be worth noting. When I delete my cache in IE, the video loads right on the first load. It fails on all subsequent loads. Seems like maybe IE is caching something it shouldn't?  Any ideas?

Comment: So, I used HTTP Watch on IE, and am able to see what's being cached. It's all coming from blip, or blip related 3rd party urls. Is there some way I can force these to not cache on my page?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the caching part, by adding the time stamp to the swf, and to the filename:

```
function loadBlip(videoFile,width,height,cssID) {
var stampStr = "?t=" + new Date().getTime(); 
var blipSWF = "http://blip.tv/scripts/flash/stratos.swf" + stampStr;
var expressSWF = "/lib/js/swfobject/expressInstall.swf";
var attributes = {
};
var flashvars = {
    file: videoFile + stampStr,
    allowsriptaccess: "true",
    enablejs: "true",
    allowfullscreen: "true",
    enablejs: "true",
    javascriptid: cssID,
    lightcolor: "0xFFFFFF",
    backcolor: "0x000000",
    autostart: "false",
    showinfo: "false"
};
var params = {
    allowfullscreen: "true",
    allowScriptAccess: "always"
};
swfobject.embedSWF(blipSWF, cssID, width, height, "9.0.124", expressSWF, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

This fixes it when there's no css hiding/unhiding of the div that contains the video. Some pages hide/unhide the videos, and these are exhibiting the same original problems.  Getting there...any suggestions?